# Trace and rank relation for diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have a matrix $P$ which is diagonalizable and satisfy the condition $P^3+P=0$ then how can I show that $\operatorname{rank}(P)=-\operatorname{tr}(P^2)$?

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $P$ are roots of $z^3+z=0$ that is $0$, $i$ and $-i$. Since $P$ is diagonalizable there exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that $P=MDM^{-1}$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix 
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
iI_r & 0 &0\\ 
0 & -iI_s &0\\
0 & 0 &0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\operatorname{rank}(P)=r+s$. Moreover
$$-P^2=-MDM^{-1}MDM^{-1}=M(-D^2)M^{-1}$$
which implies that
$$-\operatorname{tr}(P^2)=\text{tr}(-P^2)=\operatorname{tr}(-D^2)=
\operatorname{tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0 &0\\ 
0 & I_s &0\\
0 & 0 &0
\end{bmatrix}\right)
=r+s=\operatorname{rank}(P).$$

Comment: how the rank of $P$ is multiplicity of eigenvalues?

Comment: @Tien I revised completely my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: When you write \text{tr} instead of \operatorname{tr}, then you don't automatically get proper spacing in things like $a\operatorname{tr} B$ and $a\operatorname{tr}(B).$ In particular, you'll notice somewhat more space to the right of the minus sign after my edit.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for comment (and edit).

Comment: @RobertZ : I"m glad it helps.

Comment: @RobertZ yes.thank you.

Comment: @Tien Thank you for your effort!